# Pressing UITabBar icon and select.... Error Code

Tags: iphone, ios, tabbar, viewcontroller, nslog

I am using UITabbar because I like the Icon design. But I don't use UIButtons. I have two icon buttons and one label.

I've delegate method this. My NSLog won't appear if click first icon and second icon. I have this code appear warnings Xcode. How do you fix this?

```
    - (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
     if ([viewController.tabBarItem.title isEqualToString:@"FIRST"])
      { 
          label.hidden = YES;
          NSLog(@"FIRST");
       } else if ([viewController.tabBarItem.title isEqualToString:@"SECOND"])
      {
          label.hidden = NO;
          NSLog(@"SECOND");
       }

  }
```

Comment: Erm, what does the waring say exactly?

Comment: Red Underline "viewController" and Expression result unused.
tabBarItem.title doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What's `viewController`? `self.tabBarItem.title` doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

In the code you posted, you need to replace the `viewController.tabBarItem` with just `item` both of the times it appears. The tab bar item that you want to investigate is the `item` parameter passed to this method. The method is not passed a `viewController` parameter, so the `viewController` variable is undefined. That is why XCode underlines it in red.